# Memcached windows binaries for latest version

Tags: java, rest, memcached

I am trying to implement Memcached in front of my rest services .How can i get the latest **Memcached 1.6** version for windows. Everywhere i get binaries for 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find a serious and verified native Windows port for Memcached.
You will be able to run it as a service as well.

Current version is 1.6.8, and it's really faster than the usual 1.4.4 you can find everywhere (tested with PHP8).

https://github.com/jefyt/memcached-windows

A more up to date Cygwin version is available here and runs well too as a service via NSSM
https://github.com/nono303/memcached

Answer (score 0):

According to [memcached installation guide](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Install):

> There is no official support for windows builds.

This means you will either have to build it yourself or trust someone else's binary (not recommended).

You can also use [docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) and then just `docker run --name my-memcache -d memcached` (as shown [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached))